# How to use Apche Tika Server for NER

Tags: named-entity-recognition, apache-tika, tika-server

I am checking out Tika for an NER task and running the [NER example](https://github.com/apache/tika-docker). I can get my file meta data by hitting the [documented](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-TikaServerServices) meta endpoint:

```
curl -T test.txt http://localhost:9998/meta  --header "Accept: application/json" | jq
```

How do I do NER?